# Rails, Devise: If an anonymous user tries to access a page - redirect user to sign in page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I am using Devise to authenticate users in my rails app. I have couple of resources that I want only accessible to authenticated users. If unauthenticated users try to access such resources, I would like them to return to the sign in page.

I was wondering what would the best way of doing this. I was thinking:

- I could add a check in application_controller.rb - however, if I add this check, it may also apply to the sign in page, and hence we get into a loop. (enter sign in page -> user not logged in -> redirect to sign in page ...)
- Add an attribute on top of every controller method, eg. @authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read about the `authenticate_user!` filter? You can find the docs at [github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) (Search for "Controller filters and helpers").

Add this as in the relevant controllers. You can restrict it to certain actions by providing `:only => [ :show ]` or `:except => [ :index ]` as further parameters to it.

Comment: okay - that almost did the job. However, this redirects user to /user/sign_in. How can I personalise where the user is redirected if he isnt authenticated?

Comment: The chapter "Configuring routes" should give you some pointers. If not, have a look at the wiki of devise, it is really good I think covers such a problem as well.

Comment: I tried the following: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated

however, I still get the "uninitialized constant CustomFailure". Can't see what I am doing wrong

Comment: "If you’re getting an uninitialized constant CustomFailure error, and you’ve put the CustomFailure class under your /lib directory, make sure to autoload your lib files in your application.rb file, like below

`config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)`"

Comment: yeah, however, I still get that error. I made a CustomFailure.rb file right under the lib directory, pasted the contents indicated by the wiki into that file. Then I modified devise.rb to include the few lines as indicated by the instructions. Lastly, I copied and pasted that file into application.rb. Still get the same error.

Comment: AHA! the problem was that the CustomFailure class should actually be named custom_failure.rb